# How to send file by Bluetooth to a contact list of devices in Android

Tags: android, file-transfer

I want to send a file to a Bluetooth device list; I get this:

```
private void envio_brodcast() {
    String mdeviceadd="";
    File myFile = new File(_path);
    //BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(mBluetoothAdapter == null)
                     {

                     }

                     if(!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
                     {
                         Intent enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                         startActivityForResult(enableBluetooth, 0);
                     }
                     mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                     mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                     Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

                     if(pairedDevices.size() > 0)
                     {
                         for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
                         {

                             if(device.getName()!=null) 
                             { 
                                 String nombreDispocitivo=device.getName();
                                 Toast.makeText(this,nombreDispocitivo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                                     BluetoothDevice mmDevice = device;
                                     mdeviceadd = device.getAddress();
                                     Toast.makeText(this,nombreDispocitivo,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

                                     ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                     values.put(BluetoothShare.URI,_path);
                                     values.put(BluetoothShare.DESTINATION,   mdeviceadd);
                                     values.put(BluetoothShare.DIRECTION, BluetoothShare.DIRECTION_OUTBOUND);
                                     Long ts = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                     values.put(BluetoothShare.TIMESTAMP, ts);
                                     getContentResolver().insert(BluetoothShare.CONTENT_URI, values);
                             }
                         }
                     }

}
```

It does not work. If someone could send me code to send files to a specific dispocitivo with this structure:

```
public void send_file(BluetoothDevice mmDevice,Uri outputFileUri)
```

I would be very grateful.